# Hyperref and align

Tags: hyperref, align

I am working on a lengthy proof where I show by induction that (i) - (vi) holds.

During the proof I am mentioning (i), ..., (iv) several times and would like them to be hyperlinks, such that when the reader clicks on e.g. (i) the PDF jumps to this overview of (i) - (vi).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

We show by induction that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ it holds that
%
\begin{align*} 
    &\text{(i)}  &   x^{2 k}&=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} x^{0} \,,  \quad&   &\text{(iii)} & \Delta_{2 k}&=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} \Delta_{0}\,, \quad& & \text{(v)}& \rho_{2 k} &\equiv \theta \, ,\\
    &\text{(ii)} &   x^{2 k+1}&=x^{2 k} \,,                           \quad&   &\text{(iv)}  & \Delta_{2 k+1}&=\beta_{1}\left(\beta_{1} \beta_{2}\right)^{k} \Delta_{0}\,, \quad& & \text{(vi)}& \rho_{2 k+1} &\equiv 1 \, .
\end{align*}

%...
%several pages later
%...

Because of (i) and (ii) we have that ...


\end{document}
```

Comment: you have suppressed numbering by using `align*` and then numbered by hand with `\text{ii}` so neither latex nor hyperref know it's a numbered equation. Just use `align` and `\label` and `\ref` as usual and then hyperref will make them links.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I would like to use the `\text{ii}` kind of numbering because this is the way the paper where this proof is from does it. This will make it easier for my professor to follow my proof...So what you say is that I cannot achieve what I want as long as I stick to the way I do it above?

Comment: you can use any kind of numbering you want with all latex numbered constructs `\renewcommand\theequation{\roman{equation}}` will make it use lower case roman. You should more or less never number by hand anything in latex/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reworked

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hit}[2]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \phantomsection
    \expandafter\gdef\csname hit@#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \ltx@label{#1}%
  \fi
  \textup{(#2)}%
}
\newcommand{\hir}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{%
    \ifcsname hit@#1\endcsname
      \textup{(\csname hit@#1\endcsname)}%
    \else
      ??%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

We show by induction that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ it holds that
%
\begin{alignat*}{6}
         & \hit{h1}{i}\   & x^{2 k}&=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} x^{0} \,,
  &\qquad& \hit{h3}{iii}\ & \Delta_{2 k}&=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} \Delta_{0}\,,
  &\qquad& \hit{h5}{v}\   & \rho_{2 k} &\equiv \theta \,,
\\
         & \hit{h2}{ii}\  & x^{2 k+1}&=x^{2 k} \,,
  &\qquad& \hit{h4}{iv}\  & \Delta_{2 k+1}&=\beta_{1}(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} \Delta_{0}\,,
  &\qquad& \hit{h6}{vi}\  & \rho_{2 k+1} &\equiv 1 \, .
\end{alignat*}

%...
%several pages later
%...

Because of \hir{h1} and \hir{h2} we have that ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Old answer

A simple way would be to use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`; the nuisance is the need of using two arguments, but perhaps something better can be devised.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\hit}[2]{\raisebox{\fontcharht\font`T}{\hypertarget{#1}{}}{\textup{(#2)}}}
\newcommand{\hir}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{\textup{(#2)}}}

\begin{document}

We show by induction that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ it holds that
%
\begin{align*} 
   &\hit{h1}{i}   & x^{2 k}&=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} x^{0} \,,
  &&\hit{h3}{iii} & \Delta_{2 k}&=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} \Delta_{0}\,,
  &&\hit{h5}{v}   & \rho_{2 k} &\equiv \theta \,,
\\
   &\hit{h2}{ii}  & x^{2 k+1}&=x^{2 k} \,,
  &&\hit{h4}{iv}  & \Delta_{2 k+1}&=\beta_{1}(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} \Delta_{0}\,,
  &&\hit{h6}{vi}  & \rho_{2 k+1} &\equiv 1 \, .
\end{align*}

%...
%several pages later
%...

\newpage

Because of \hir{h1}{i} and \hir{h2}{ii} we have that ...


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's absolutely crucial to show the six criteria in an `align` setting, I'd use an inline `enumerate` list.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

We show by induction that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ it holds that
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*)] 
\item $x^{2 k}=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} x^{0}$\label{item:1}, 
\item $x^{2 k+1}=x^{2 k}$\label{item:2},
\item $\Delta_{2 k}=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} \Delta_{0}$, 
\item $\Delta_{2 k+1}=\beta_{1}(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k} \Delta_{0}$,
\item $\rho_{2 k} \equiv \theta$, and
\item $\rho_{2 k+1} \equiv 1$.
\end{enumerate*}

Because of \labelcref{item:1,item:2} we have \dots
\end{document}
```